# Update using data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want the minimum price from `Table 2` to be filled in `price` column of `Table 1` for a particular id.

**Table 1**

```
pid price
111 0
222 0
333 0
```

**Table 2**

```
pid price
111 100
111 200
222 120
222 90
333 200
333 150
```

**Expected output: Table 1**

```
pid price
111 100
222 90
333 150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
UPDATE Table1 t 
SET t.price = (SELECT MIN(t2.price) FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.pid = t.pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is query to get lowest price from table2
(SELECT  price  FROM table2  WHERE  price =  ( SELECT MIN(price)  FROM table2 )  )  now you can update the table 1      ( update table1 set price="result you got from above query" where id=given id)